# Performing a WHIRLPOOL hash in C++

Tags: c++, hash, cryptography, crypto++, whirlpool

This sounds like a relatively simple question, but I haven't been able to get Crypto++ to work. I'm using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express (I'm cheap) and the .vcxproj/.vcproj/.sln files included in the library simply don't work. There are a lot of files, too, and I'm just not sure what exactly I need.

So does anyone know of a solution I could just drop in or something? Reference implementations are fine as long as they're not ridiculously inefficient or something. Sorry for such a mundane question, but I've looked around myself and I couldn't find anything I need - I guess cryptography just isn't my area of expertise.

That being said, though, it would be nice to get Crypto++ to work, if anyone has a clue as to how I might get VC++ 2010 to load the project files. The error is extremely... not descriptive. It just says the project couldn't be loaded and gives me -2147483647 as an error number.

EDIT: Here's the Conversion Report error:

The following error has occurred during XML parsing: File: C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Exoterra\Dependencies\crypto\cryptlib.vcproj Line: 102 Column: 5 Error Message: System error: -2147154677. The file 'C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\Exoterra\Dependencies\crypto\cryptlib.vcproj' has failed to load.

This is line 102 of cryptlib.vcproj:

```
Name="VCPostBuildEventTool"
```

**EDIT (again):** I got it to work. I deleted everything referring to x64 in the project file and now it converted properly. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what problem you had.

1. Download version *5.6.1*;
2. Unzip the downloaded archive;
3. Double click on *cryptest.sln*;
4. Visual Studio will open and ask if you want to convert the project;
5. Say *yes*;
6. After a while Visual Studio will show the converted solution;

With the Express version you want be able to compile the resource files in Visual Studio. You will need to use the rc compiler from the Windows SDK to compile them.

Comment: Yes, I've followed those steps exactly, several times. I even tried 5.6.0 even though VS2010 isn't listed as supported. Every project file supposedly has an XML error.